# if statement and segmentation fault - c++

Tags: c++, if-statement, segmentation-fault, treenode

I have an if/else if statement that looks like this:

```
if(myNode->left->is_red){
    //CODE TO EXECUTE
}               
else if(myNode->right->is_red){
    //CODE TO EXECUTE
}
```

The conditions I am checking are whether certain data fields in each node are set. BUT, the problem is, if I access a NULL pointer and try to access its members (which don't exist), then I run into a segmentation fault issue. But if I do an if statement before the if, and again before the else if, to check whether or not the node is NULL, then I lose the ability to use an if/else if statement.

Is there any way I can achieve a solution to both problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming the issue is that `left` and/or `right` is NULL, hence your segfault?

If so, then use AND.

e.g:

```
if((myNode->left != NULL) && myNode->left->is_red){
    //CODE TO EXECUTE
}               
else if((myNode->right != NULL) && myNode->right->is_red){
    //CODE TO EXECUTE
}
```

This uses [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation): although the `myNode->left->is_red` and `myNode->right->is_red` are still in the `if` conditions, if `myNode->left` is `NULL` (or `myNode->right` respectively), they wont be evaluated and you will not have your segfault.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I wasn't sure how to do it in the same statement. This helped tremendously!

Comment: @Jordy: I'm really glad. Did [ryanbwork's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13871608/214149) help at all?

Comment: Yes it did. Both were helpful. I upvoted both, but saw your answer first. That's why I accepted yours

Comment: @Jordy: Ok, that's fair enough. Given that both answers said basically the same but his was squeezed in about 30 seconds before mine, I just wanted to make sure you were making an informed decision before awarding the accept. Sounds like that's the case though, so thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Check to see if the pointers aren't null in the if statement:

```
if(myNode != NULL && myNode->left != NULL && myNode->left->is_red){
{ 
   // code goes here
}
```

Comment: @Jordy, note this is the preferred method and will work because of the short-circuiting while using `&&` (AND) logic.  You might want to think about whether you want different behavior if the pointers are `NULL` in which case you can use nested `if` statements.